# Action Menu in IOS 7

Tags: ios, action, toolbar, uitoolbar

I'm looking for the menu that pops up when you want to set a photo as wallpaper, where you have a series of options. I'm going to link this to a Action BarButtonItem in a ToolBar and was wondering if you know of any good tutorials for this or have got some code if it's a short and easy thing to do?

I know this is a short question but I really need answer to this, at least to know what the menu is "officially" called ;)

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean `UIActionSheet` (or `UIAlertController` in iOS 8)? Or do you mean the `UIActivityViewController`?

Comment: It's the UIActionSheet I'm looking for ;) @rmaddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are looking for UIActionSheet. These guys have pretty good tutorials. I watched all their tutorials and I think [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qlZ6cHcfJ80) one will help you out with that.

This is what UIActionSheet Looks like in iOS 7

[image: UIActionSheet]